# Prime numbers $p$ such that $p-1$ has no small odd factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

I am interested in a (simple) proof of this result:

> There exists $\alpha>0$ and infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p-1$ does not have any odd prime factor smaller than $p^\alpha$.

I know that one can do much better by using complicated sieves, such as the Brun-Hooley sieve or the "lower bound sieve" as seen in Cojocaru & Murty, chapter 10, for instance, but I am only interested in this weaker form and a simpler proof.

I tried using Brun's pure sieve and the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem but it didn't really work out. If my original question is too complicated, I would also appreciate a simple proof of this (slightly weaker) result:

> There exists $C$ and infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $\omega(p-1)<C$.

Edit: I wish to clarify that I intend to find a proof with a reduced degree of technicality when it comes to the sieving part. I do allow the usage of powerful theorems, such as Bombieri-Vinogradov.

Comment: Does $p=17$ count as an example?  *All* the odd prime factors of $16$ are bigger than $p^\alpha$

Comment: Yes, it counts as an example (but of course, we don't know if there are infinitely many Fermat primes, so this class of primes won't help)

Comment: It looks like what you are looking for essentially comes down to the lower bound sieve. A crucial component of the lower bound sieve is Bombieri-Vinogradov. In my opinion, if you allow Bombieri-Vinogradov, you are allowing the lower bound sieve.

Comment: I never said I don’t allow the lower bound sieve, just that I hope to find a simpler proof. In particular, in Cojocaru & Murty, they pay close attention to $\alpha$ (making it big). I presume that if we do not care about the size of $\alpha$, but only its existance, then there exists a simpler proof - and this is essentially my question.

Comment: The issue of Brun's pure sieve is that it only provides an error term in the form $O(z^{K\log\log z})$, but for a sieve to produce an effective lower bound you need an error term of the form $O(z^\beta)$ for some fixed $\beta>0$, which can only be done using Brun's main theorem or Brun-Hooley sieve.

Comment: Another convenient tool to establish such results is called the [fundamental lemma of sieve theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_sieve_theory), which can be proved using either Brun's main theorem or Selberg's sieve.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite a proof yet, but I'm pretty sure you can get  $α>0.5$ because for most primes $q$ there exists a prime $p$ such that $p=kq+1$ for $k \leq q$. For any given $q$, we expect roughly $q/2\ln (q)$ of the $k$ values to yield a prime $p$.

I'm actually pretty sure this let's you get $α$ arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: You can get $\alpha=1/7$ with some careful sieving, but I’m not interested in having large values of $\alpha$ (which makes the problem more difficult). I want to prove that an $\alpha$ simply exists.

Comment: doesn't my answer give you a>.5 pretty easily? if each q yields on average q/ln(q^2) primes less than q^2, that proves infinitely many p with a prime factor q greater than sqrt(p)

Comment: Your answer is only a heuristic. Also, I’m not sure if you understood my question correctly, I want ALL the odd prime factors of  $p-1$ to be greater than $p^\alpha$.

Comment: oh yeah. I did misunderstand. that's a way harder condition to fulfill...